# R - Get value by comparing the begin and end date

Tags: r, return, compare

I have two dataframes named 'holiday' and 'script':

holidays:

```
 BeginDate   EndDate      Holiday
 2012-01-01  2012-01-05   Candyday
 2014-02-13  2014-02-16   Toplessday
```

script:

```
Date    
2012-01-04
2014-02-17
```

What I would like to have is to add another column to the 'script' dataframe which contains the holiday by comparing the dates.

You can assume that all the date values are formatted as date; %Y%m%d.
The holiday value is formatted as characters.

Comment: the package lubridate should make this easy, see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

Answer (score -1):

This should do it. It also takes care of overlapping holidays using paste.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

holi <- read.table(text=" BeginDate   EndDate      Holiday
            2012-01-01  2012-01-05   Candyday
            2014-02-13  2014-02-17   Toplessday
            2012-01-01  2014-03-17  Everyday", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

script <- read.table(text="Date    
            2012-01-04
            2014-02-15", header=T)

holi <- transmute(holi, Interval=interval(ymd(BeginDate), ymd(EndDate)), Holiday)


script <- transmute(script, Date=ymd(Date))

holiday_vec <- sapply(script$Date, function(x){
    paste(holi$Holiday[x %within% holi$Interval], 
             collapse = ", ")})

script <- mutate(script, Holidays = holiday_vec)
```